# Метод, который обьединяет два массива в один

Tags: java, массивы

Кто то может подсказать пожалуйста? Написал вот такой метод, используя `arrayCopy`.

Проблема заключается в том что в массив `arrayOfCarriages` записываются только элементы массива `carriagePKs`. Элементы массива `carriageCoupes` отображаются как `null`.

```
public void addCarriages(Carriage [] carriageCoupes, Carriage[] carriagePKs){
    arrayOfCarriages = new Carriage[carriageCoupes.length + carriagePKs.length];
    System.arraycopy(carriagePKs, 0, arrayOfCarriages, 0, carriagePKs.length);
    System.arraycopy(carriageCoupes, 0, arrayOfCarriages, carriagePKs.length, carriageCoupes.length);
}
```

Comment: Наверное у вас массивы одинаковой длины и записываете вы их в Новый с нулевого индеска

Comment: Приведенный код [нормально работает](http://ideone.com/CXWJ4L), массив заполняется. Проблема где-то в другом месте.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Стандартными средствами, тоже можно получить однострочник:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T> T[] concat(T[] a1, T[] a2) {
    return (T[]) Stream.concat(of(a1), of(a2)).toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Однострочник с либой Apache Commons Lang library.

```
 ArrayUtils.addAll(T[], T...)
```

В вашем случае

```
 Carriage[] both = (Carriage[])ArrayUtils.addAll(first, second);
```

Без либ так:

```
public Carriage[] concat(Carriage[] a, Carriage[] b) {
   int aLen = a.length;
   int bLen = b.length;
   Carriage[] c= new Foo[aLen+bLen];
   System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, aLen);
   System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, aLen, bLen);
   return c;
}
```